# ASP.NET Data cannot output when code is run but shows value if in debug mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to show the calculated value of the products and category to the side navigation bar.
When the page is at the home page it works exactly as expected. but when I navigate to the product page it fails. The same code of the following works for the home page but fails for the category page.

[Working Homepage navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8pnE.png)

Same code but not working for category page.

```
      public IActionResult Index()
           
        {
            dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
            var ProductDbContext = _context.Product.Include(p => p.Categories);
            var CategoryDbContext = _context.Category;
            mymodel.products = ProductDbContext;
            mymodel.P_Category = CategoryDbContext;
            return View(mymodel);
        }
```

Layout code

```
 @foreach (Category category in Model.P_Category)
                            {
                                <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a href="pages/layout/top-nav.html" class="nav-link">
                                            <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => category.Category_Name)</p>
                                            @category.Products.Count()
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            }
```

The error message

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
System.Linq.Enumerable.Count<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout.<ExecuteAsync>b__76_1() in _Layout.cshtml
+
                                            @category.Products.Count()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout.ExecuteAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you didnt convert result to list . Thats why you getting error.
public IActionResult Index()

```
    {
        dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
        var ProductDbContext = _context.Product.Include(p => p.Categories).ToList();//You need the convert list here
        var CategoryDbContext = _context.Category;
        mymodel.products = ProductDbContext;
        mymodel.P_Category = CategoryDbContext;
        return View(mymodel);
    }
```

Comment: Please tell me how I will use this code in a controller for all Action Method like (index, create, edit) @SadullahDOĞAN

Comment: What you mean for all actions can u be more specific please .

Comment: I don't want to write the same code in all methods for showing the data on my layout page. how I will fix this?

Comment: You can use PartialView for this. Create one Partial View and call your layout page.

Answer (score 0):

**@category.Products.Count()**

According to your error message, no value is assigned to it when querying. It may be that the data type is not converted after querying, you can try this.

```
//Convert datatype to List
var ProductDbContext = _context.Product.Include(p => p.Categories).ToList();
var CategoryDbContext = _context.Category.ToList();
//...
```

I set the property of `ExpandoObject`.

```
public class ExpandoObject
{
    public List<Product> products { get; set; }
    public List<Category> P_Category { get; set; }
}
```